# what's the best practice for page lock in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, large-data

I've got a server with this properties:
system type:   64 bit
windows:       server 2008 R2
Sql Server:    2008 R2
Database Size: 20 Gigabyte
RAM: 16 GB

I have enabled lock page in windows and sql server is using of it now. performance seems good.
I want to know that it'a a correct way? or unusual? what's best practice?

Comment: You take baseline performance measurements for our workload then you change the configuration and take the same measurements and compare. There is no right or wrong way, especially based on the provided details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is actually to lock pages in memory.

SQL Server uses the memory as cache to avoid disc IO. If that cache ends out being swapped to disc that sort of totally kills the sense of having cache in the first place.

So, you absolutely want to make sure that:

- You do not assign more memory than you can physically use and
- YOu can lock that in memory.

THAT SAID: If that is a SQL Server ONLY (as a larger install should be) there is little sense in acutally locking as there is nothing that is forcing that memory off the hardware. I typically do not even do that - but if you have a small machine that doubles as application server you may want to make sure that your sql server is not ending getting partially off the memory.

All this, though, is not related to programming so not a question per se for stackoverflow...